# Installing Plotty on Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Plotty in PyCharm. When I try to add it in the 'Python Interpriter' Install section it can only find plottyprint.

How can I get Plotty to install?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Plotty seems to be a JavaScript library? - https://github.com/santilland/plotty

Comment: Do you mean https://pypi.org/project/plotly/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly is not a standard Python package, so you will need to install it using a different method. Here's how you can install Plotly,
In terminal run

`pip install plotly`

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the "plotty" package you are refering to on the internet. So, it could be that a typo is the reason why you are not finding the package in pycharm.

[image: plotly]

If the plotty package is a custom package, then [you might want to include the source repository where the package resides, into the source repository configuration for pycharm.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#custom-repositories) The referenced documentation provides much more information on how to install packages into pycharm.